# How to handle M:M entity relationships in Flex/Java web application?

Tags: java, apache-flex, hibernate, blazeds, jpa-2.0

I am struggling to come up with a way to ***efficiently*** manage Flex entities that have a many-to-many relationships between their JPA/Java counter parts.

Here is the problem...imagine a movie review web application with two entities:

```
@Entity
Class Movie {
 List<Viewer> Viewers;
}

@Entity
Class Viewer {
 List<Movie> Movies;
}
```

Both of these entities can exist independently of each other and both have a 1:M relationship with the other.  The relationship is not really owned by one side or the other.

Within the application there are Flex UI's that sometimes want to see viewers based on movies and other UI's that want to see movies based on viewers.

Currently both the `Movies.Viewers` and `Viewers.Movies` collections are lazy loaded by JPA which works fine.  The problem is that every time I ask a viewer for it's list of movies, then they all get sent over the wire and then within Flex I end up with a bunch of Movie objects that (often, not always) duplicate the ones I already have there.

It seems inefficient at best and could likely cause errors if the duplicate objects are not dealt with.

In my real application I have tons of these types of relationships all over some very large object graphs.

It almost seems to me that the lazy loaded object collections need to be turned into eagerly loaded collections of foreign keys which are used to explicitly load objects on the Flex side of things.  But this seems like I am writing a JPA provider in Flex! Is the correct answer to never store state in a Flex application? (Yikes) HELP!!

**Update:**

I should add that all my value objects have a UID that is created on the server side, so I could somehow use that to find/remove duplicates on the Flex side. But how?

Comment: Have you actually verified that your JPA provider is creating multiple copies of the same entity?  It's likely that on the server side of things you have multiple references to the same copy which isn't a big issue.  Now I wouldn't doubt you're getting multiple copies when sent over the wire.  I don't think the issue is JPA related however.

Comment: You are correct, JPA is fine, the problem is on the Flex side.  Every time I use RemoteObject in Flex to retrieve a lazily loaded collection I get all of the entities coming back to Flex, but some/most of them are already there.  So they are duplicated on the Flex side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing you can do about the backend returning new instances of the same objects you already have in memory. Having multiple instances refering to the same entities (based on value, not memory location) can lead to some unexpected results though when searching and filtering. That is because a simple === on 2 different entities will not always be true on what seems to be the same entity because they refer to 2 different objects in memory.

I would suggest to add custom equality methods to your entities instead of relying on ===. In the case of entities, the equality will be based on the id, which is most likely also the database id. In case of value objects, equality is based on the state of the objects.

Also, I would not try to keep much state on the client. I know this seems like an attractive solution and that it is promoted in some of the Flex architetural frameworks, since after all you are building a rich client, but in my experience this leads to many scenarios where data is out of date and causes problems further down the road. Unless you are working with managed data (as in LCDS) I would prefer querying the backend instead of using the client state.

As a last note: the m-m relation is a database implementation detail in my opinion and should not be translated into the domain of both client and server. I would much rather create service methods that query the movies by a viewer or vice versa. There is some good material on this topic in the DDD writings of Eric Evans.

Comment: I am fortunate to already have UUID on every object.  The idea of adding my own ActionScript method for equality on all the value objects is a great idea.  Do you know if there is any way to get ActionScript to call my Equals function via the "==" operator?  Coming from a Java background here....

Comment: Apparently not:  http://blog.iconara.net/2007/11/25/architectural-atrocities-part-8-is-there-no-equality/

Answer (score 1):

LCDS tried to solve this problem for you, by using data management - however I'm not sure if it's still on the roadmap or not. So yes, by using the straight approach (trying to duplicate the model with all the relationships on the client) probably you could end by writing your own entity manager in Flex, assuming that you have an unlimited amount of time.

In my case I'm using BlazeDS and I've start creating simpler objects for the client. For example if I would need all the movies I would create something like a MovieVO transport object and I would create the list of the objects from the list of Movies. Depending on the specification I will add more information into the MovieVO (like a variable counting the number of viewers, or a simplified list of viewers). Basically I'm simplifying the model on the client a lot. The drawback is that I have to write/modify a lot of glue code.

I'm very curious to hear another approaches, especially from developers using weborb/graniteds.

Comment: For now, I am trying to avoid the creation of an isometric set of DTO classes (feeling less confident in this by the minute). While this approach would mean sending fewer properties over the wire (and fewer remote service calls), I don't think it would reduce duplicate objects sent over the wire.  I still have the problem where a collection of MovieVO objects under a ViewerVO object contains a MovieVO that is already in another UI view and has been modified but not persisted yet.  Thus I have two instances of the same Movie with the same UID, but different property values.